# How do I reset application.cfc without resetting the server instance?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, application.cfc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [restart application without restarting server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119119/restart-application-without-restarting-server)

How do I reset a Coldfusion Application / application.cfc without resetting the Coldfusion Server instance? If I remember right, there are a few tricks out there such as creating a reinit function within application.cfc or renaming the file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A couple of steps:

First, make sure all your application initialization logic is contained inside the OnApplicationStart method of your CFC. If it has nested calls, that is fine - just so long as you can re-initialize your application easily through a single call makes your life much easier.

Second, this is the code I use in the OnRequestStart method of application.cfc

```
<cfif structKeyExists(url,'resetappvars')>
  <cfset OnApplicationStart() />
</cfif>
```

Feel free to use whatever coded value you would like in place of **resetAppVars**.

Comment: don't forget: <cfcache action="flush">

Answer (score 7):

[CF9 Doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSB51B3786-8E55-4a72-ABDB-5707B9A853D9.html):

> To restart the application, you can
>   stop the application using
>   **ApplicationStop()** and the next request
>   to any page in this application
>   automatically starts it.

ApplicationStop() is new in ColdFusion 9.

Comment: Wow, that's a handy new feature! :-) Does anyone know if this is in the other CFML engines too?

Answer (score 3):

If you're on CF8 and using the "if reinit, then call onApplicationStart()" approach, make sure you avoid race conditions. This is a good explanation: http://blog.bullamakanka.net/2009/12/coldfusion-shared-scopes-and-race.html